# Adding values to a multidimensional associative array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Im trying to build a site messaging system for all of my information messages using an array i can loop through. I am trying to do it so i can separate the messages in the array (Also so they can be added appropriately)

The test code i have is

```
<?php

$test_messasge = array
(
    array("successMessage" => array()),
    array("informationMessage" => array()),
    array("errorMessage" => array()),
    array("warningMessage" => array()),
    array("message" => array())
);
var_dump($test_messasge);

echo "<br />";
echo "<br />";

$test_message['message'][] = "I am message 1";
$test_message["message"][] = "I am message 2";
$test_message["errorMessage"][] = "I am errorMessage 1";
$test_message["informationMessage"][] = "I am informationMessage 1";

foreach($test_messasge['message'] as $message){
    echo $message . "<br />";
}
echo "<br />";
echo "<br />";
var_dump($test_messasge);

?>
```

After adding the messages via $test_message['message'][] = "Whatever" in my var dumps it is shown as empty, When i do the loop it get the error "Undefined index: message"

Am i going about this wrong ? Is there a better way to do this rather than using a multidimensional array ?

Cheers in advance 
Ryan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your loop, please change your variable name `$test_messasge` to `$test_message`

```
foreach ($test_message['message'] as $message){
    echo $message . "<br />";
}
```